# Requests only returns head section, not the body section

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to web scrape this link "https://www.blocket.se/annonser/hela_sverige?q=dunjacka" ,but when I do that I only get info of the head section, not the body section, which is the part i am trying to extract information from.

This is my code:

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import requests

variable = input("Sökord:")
URL = ("https://www.blocket.se/annonser/hela_sverige?q=" + variable)

page_raw = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_raw.content, "html.parser")

print (soup)
```

I am new to both web-scraping and programming in general, is there anything I am doing wrong?

I've tried the same code but with another website (i copied it just to try it out) and it worked when i did that. This is the code with the other website:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

variable = input("What word would you like to search: ")
url = "https://realpython.github.io/fake-jobs/" + variable
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
results = soup.find(id="ResultsContainer")

job_elements = results.find_all("div", class_="card-content")


for job_element in job_elements:
    title_element = job_element.find("h2", class_="title")
    company_element = job_element.find("h3", class_="company")
    location_element = job_element.find("p", class_="location")
    print(title_element.text.strip())
    print(company_element.text.strip())
    print(location_element.text.strip())
    print()
```

I tried seeing what code got extracted by using this code:

```
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup
import requests

variable = input("Sökord:")
URL = ("https://www.blocket.se/annonser/hela_sverige?q=" + variable)

page_raw = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page_raw.content, "html.parser")

print (soup)
```

All code for the head section was returned but no code for the body section, this is the end of the returned code:

```
</script></body></html>
```

Comment: are you sure it returns only the head? I've checked the url you provided and there is a body section in the response.

Comment: @IgorMoraru It returns the all code in the head and then "</body>",  but nothing else, the information I need is within the body section.

Comment: the `</script>` tag is part of the body, not the head. a html page can contain <script> tags also in the body. you can copy the response text in a text editor and search for `<body>` start tag. you'll see that there is a lot of code after it. try to find the information you need manually, then proceed to code.